# The use of ci when specifying locations

Tags: adverbs, pronouns, particles

The particle *ci* is often used when replacing a prepositional phrase introduced by ***a*** [+ location].

> Sei andato a Parigi questo weekend? No, non ci sono andato.

But why does the following example need the particle *ne*?

> Sei andato al supermercato? Sì, ne sono appena uscito.

Does it have anything to do with the change in the verb *uscire* in the response, since *uscire is often followed by **di*** and *ne* usually replaces prepositional phrases that use *di*?

Comment: I had actually upvoted because of the creation of the tags **ci** and **ne**. The words are so problematic for me, that I thought it would make sense to keep them. Maybe for others isn't?

Comment: @c.p.: I'm not sure about that. Maybe it's something to discuss in "Italian Language meta".

Comment: I've posed a question about these tags in Meta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the first answer, *ci* is *moto a luogo* (motion to), whereas in the second answer *ne* is *moto da luogo* (motion from).

If you expand them, you get

> No, non sono andato a Parigi

and

> Sì, sono appena uscito dal supermercato

According to the [Treccani dictionary](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/), *ci* for *moto da luogo* is uncommon (*non com.*). See also the [entry for *ne*](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/ne1/).