What is the purpose of Ci in this sentence?
50Languages includes this sentence in its Italian work:

Ci viene anche Lei?

What does Ci add to this sentence? How does it differ from

Lei viene anche?


What is “50Languages”?

50Languages.com: it is the next to last sentence on this page: https://www.50languages.com/en/learn/phrasebook-lessons/183/it

Related: https://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5328/.

"Ci" can be an adverb of place when the meaning is 'here, in this place; there, in that place' (associated with state or motion with verbs like “come”).
The sentence without "ci" sounds better if you change the word order in this way:

Viene anche lei?


It doesn't sound either better nor worse: it's a different sentence with a slightly different meaning.

Welcome to Italian.SE! With your last sentence do you mean something like The sentence without "ci" sounds better if you change the word order in this way: "Viene anche lei?"?

Correct. It is exactly what I meant.

This response was from Raffaele Zanotti:

In that sentence I imagine it refers to a place that has been mentioned before, someone is going there and is asking the other person "are you coming (there) too? If that is the situation I would prefer to say "viene anche Lei?". Whereas with "andare" I think I would say "ci va anche Lei?"

His answer confirms Antonio Di Tosto's, edited by Charo.

Sorry, who's Raffaele Zanotti?

There is no answer by Charo. Which answer are you referring to?

Raffaele Zanotti: click on the link, embedded in the name Raffaele Zanotti above.

You're quoting him, it would be nice to understand why you consider him a reliable source.

If you insist: Raffaele Zanotti, Lecturer in Italian, Department of Language and Linguistic Science, University of York, York, YO10 5DD, United Kingdom

One of the uses of "Ci" in Italian is to mean "there" when referring to a place.
For example, “Vado al mare d’estate.” (I go to the beach in summer), we can remove “al mare” (to the beach) if it's mentioned before in the conversation, and we say: “Ci vado d’estate” (I go there in summer).
But it makes more sense with "andare" (to go) than with "venire" (to come) as in your example.

Welcome to Italian.SE! Why should it make less sense with the verb venire?
